# Устойчивая сортировка строк двумерного ArrayList по возрастанию 1-ого столбца

Tags: java

Как сделать устойчивую сортировку строк двумерного ArrayList по возрастанию 1-ого столбца?

```
List<List<Integer>> lstInt = new ArrayList<>();
```

На входе:

```
  lstInt ={
          { 3,8,5},
          { 5,7,4},
          { 4,9,5}
          { 1,9,4}, }
```

На выходе:

```
 lstInt ={
         { 1,9,4},
         { 3,8,5},
         { 4,9,5}
         { 5,7,4}, }
```

Comment: Напишите компаратор.

Comment: Мне нужна именно устойчивая сортировка

Comment: Помогите сделать, пожалуйста

Comment: а чем вам компаратор не нравится?

Comment: Нет, всем нравится, только я не знаю, как он будет выглядеть для двумерного list

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
 List < List < Integer >> lstInt = asList(
     asList(3, 8, 5),
     asList(5, 7, 4),
     asList(4, 9, 5),
     asList(1, 9, 4));

Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
        return Integer.compare(left.get(0), right.get(0));
    }
};

 Collections.sort(lstInt, comparator);    

 System.out.println(lstInt);
```

> [[1, 9, 4], [3, 8, 5], [4, 9, 5], [5, 7, 4]]

Comment: Спасибо, а как в обратном порядке отсортировать, меняю .sort на .reverse и не работает ?

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов напишите `comparator.reversed()`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, отлично, разобрался

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов `Collections.reverse()` нужно использовать сортировки.